# App in production crashes immediately after showing splash screen (Android only)

Tags: react-native

Yesterday I release my app but I have problem on Android. When the app starts it shows the splash screen and crashes immediately (before actually showing any part of the app) with the message “Unfortunately App has stopped”. I build the release with the following

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

and everything was successful. I tested the app with

```
react-native run-android —variant=release
```

on my device and there wasn’t any problem. But in production it’s not working… What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually It turns out that the problem was with managing my production releases in the Google Play Store. My first release was build from the Android Studio and not from the console with ./gradlew assembleRelease (I thought that this is just another way and did it in the standard way of building release for android app). Because of that all the JavaScript needed to run my app wasn't bundled in the APK and it was showing only the splash screen. After fixing that and releasing the new APK with the bundled JavaScript and fixing the right release on the Google Play Console everything is fine now.

The documentation is very good and clear: [Releasing on Android documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)